# exception in thread main java.lang.noclassdeffounderror after build with ant

Tags: java, ant

I builded and deployed a project using the following ant script:

```
<?xm1 vertion="1.0" ?>
<project name="my project" default="build" basedir=".">

    <path id="project-classpath">
        <fileset dir="lib" includes="*.jar" />
    </path>
    
    <target name="build">
        <echo>Build</echo>
        <antcall target="clean"/>
        <antcall target="init"/>
        <antcall target="compile"/>
        <antcall target="package"/>
        <antcall target="deploy"/>
    </target>
    
    <target name="clean">
        <echo>Clean</echo>
        <delete dir="build/classes"/>
        <delete dir="dist"/>
    </target>
    
    <target name="init" depends="clean">
        <echo>Init</echo>
        <mkdir dir="build/classes"/>
        <mkdir dir="dist"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile" depends="init">
        <echo>Compile</echo>
        <javac srcdir="src/myproject" destdir="build/classes"  classpathref="project-classpath"/>
    </target>

    <target name= "package" depends= "compile">
        <echo>Package</echo>
        <jar destfile="dist/project.jar" basedir="build/classes">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="myproject.Main"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>

    <target name="deploy" depends="package">
        <echo>Deploy</echo>
        <echo message="Dir: ${user.home}"/>
        <copy todir="${user.home}">
            <fileset dir="dist"/>
        </copy>
    </target>
    
</project>
```

When I check my dir where I deploy the jar file I find the file project.jar, but when I run it using the command:

> java -jar project.jar

I have the following some errors:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> javax/ws/rs/core/MultivaluedMap at
> java.lang.Class.getDeclarativeMethods0(Native Method)...

(If I run using the IDE it works fine.)

In my project.jar I have the following tree structure:

project.jar

.....myproject           (folder)

..........Main.class     (file)

.....META-INF            (folder)

..........MANIFEST.MF    (file)

And the file MANIFEST.MF contains the following:

> Manifest-Version: 1.0
>
> Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.9.6
>
> Created-By: 1.7.0_79-b14 (Oracle Corporation)
>
> Main-Class: myproject.Main

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to include a **javax.ws.rs-api** jar library in your classpath when you run your jar.

```
java -classpath javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar -jar project.jar
```

Comment: how can I see the version of jsr311 I am using? When I see the project I see that one of the libs is javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar, is anything to do with this lib?

Comment: Yes, I guess you could use that one.

Comment: Are you using Eclipse? Enable the "Link with Editor" feature, find a method or a class of that library you are using in your code, place the cursor on it and press F3: in which jar do you end up?

Comment: After doing that it opens a new tab of the jar file javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar.

Comment: Are you putting javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar in the same directory of project.jar?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93816/discussion-between-lulas-and-simimmo).

Answer (score 1):

`NoClassDefFoundError` means that the class was present at compile-time but is missing at run-time.
In other words, `javax/ws/rs/core/MultivaluedMap` is not present in the classpath when you run your generated jar.

In your IDE, your project is using external libreries (jars) that are not included in your generated jar.

So you need to add to the classpath needed libraries, in this case, `jsr311-api`.